# How to prevent setting of computed properties with Entity Framework database-first approach?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-database-first

In SQL Server, I have a database table with a computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE Test 
(
    Field1 DECIMAL(19, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT(0),
    Field2 AS Field1
)
```

For `Field2`, on updating `.edmx` from database, I get:

```
<Property Name="Field2" Type="decimal" Precision="19" Scale="2" StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed" Nullable="false" />
```

and the corresponding generated DAL class has:

```
public partial class Test
{
    public decimal Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have some code that (falsely) tries to update the computed column:

```
var myTest = myDbContext.Test.Where(...).First();
myTest.Field2 = 1.0M;
myDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

The result is that saving the changes just fails silently, whereas the assignment should have failed in compilation already.

Basically, this is easy to fix by changing the set method on `Field2` to be private:

```
public partial class Test
{
    public decimal Field2 { get; private set; }
}
```

The problem is that the change needs to be done to the generated code, and the next time someone re-generates the code, the change is easily lost.

Question: is it possible to get the generated code right automatically, i.e., to not have a public set method on computed database columns?

Comment: See the duplicate, also change the Setter to private.

Comment: @GertArnold If you make the setter private then how will EF be able to populate it when selecting records?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning EF has no problems with private setters.

Comment: @GertArnold: Changing the Setter to private does not resolve the problem. It does change the `.edmx` content, but the generated DAL code still has a public set method. Maybe I am doing something wrong, but I would like to know, what is it that I am doing wrong. In addition, editing the Setters is still the kind of manual work I was trying to avoid. IMO, this question is not a duplicate. To me, it seems that the answer is "no, it is not possible" and the (better) workaround is the approach that I have used (edit the generated DAL code instead of the `.edmx` file).

Comment: You probably didn't regenerate the model (rerun the t4 template). Setting setters as private really does modify the generated code.

Comment: @GertArnold: Yes, you are right. Now it works. I guess it is pretty much the same to maintain these settings in either `.edmx` or the DAL classes. One needs to modify the code manually after re-generation in both the approaches. We need to check all the changes in generation line by line anyhow, so this is not much of an additional burden.

Comment: No. The changes in the EDMX are permanent. They prescribe how each class is generated. That's why changes like that should always be made in the EDMX and not in generated code. There are some unfortunate exceptions to this rule, but I consider them bugs rather than features. This change of setters is not one of them, fortunately.

Comment: @GertArnold: Yes, you are right. The changes in the EDMX are not overwritten when the model is re-generated from the database. Excellent!